# Ivy not downloading secondary dependency on Jar

Tags: maven, ant, dependencies, ivy

We are having a bit of a transitive issue between Ivy and Maven:

- We have a project called `ivylib`. `Ivylib` is an Ant/Ivy project that depends upon another project called `mvnlib`.
- Mvnlib depends upon another project called `jersey-client`. This in turn depends upon `jersey-core`. Both of these are part of the `com.sun.jersey` `groupId`.

In the Mvnlib `pom.xml` file, we have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.19</version>
```

Looking at the `jersey-client` project, I see the following dependency in its `pom.xml` file:

```
<profiles>
    ....
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In the `ivy.xml` file of the Ivylib project, we have the following dependency:

```
<dependency org="com.travelclick"       name="ivylib"
    rev="2.1"                   conf="compile->default"/>
```

All dependencies of Mvnlib are downloaded and included in Ivylib except for the secondary dependency of the `jersey-core` jar.

I suspect it has something to do with this dependency being inside a `<profile>` dependency rather than being listed in the file itself. I was wondering if there's anyway to get the **core** jar to download.

For now, we simply inlcude the `jersey-core` jar in our Mvnlib project, but I was wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to check your cache location for your IVY resolve.  Once I looked at the dependency list for jersey-client, I noticed that "jersey-core" is not one of them.  See below the ivy-1.19.xml file generated from the POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.2" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
    <dependency org="com.sun.net.httpserver" name="http" rev="20070405" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
    <dependency org="org.osgi" name="osgi_R4_core" rev="1.0" force="true" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)"/>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

I would just add another dependency to my Ivy file.  Copy/Paste the "jersey-cleint" dependency line and change to "jersey-core".  It would be nice if the POM had "jersey-core" listed properly though wouldn't it? :-)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. The question I have is why does the dependency download in our Maven project, but not the Ivy one. I can see that jersey-core is a dependency, and usually Ivy downloads all dependencies, but this time, it didn't.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give a specific answer.  Looking at the POM specification, you can put <dependencies/> in the profile section.  My bet is that Ivy is not properly parsing it.  I couldn't find a way to log the issue with the Apache Ivy team, but I'd sure like to.